# Chrome plugin not working to disable CORS restrictions or something is just wrong with my request

Tags: angular, api, cors, preflight

I'm trying to build an app that uses the Jira server API. My requests from localhost are blocked by the CORS policy.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/user?username=myname@company.com' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I read this that [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-orign-cors-changer/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc) can circumvent the CORS restrictions by adjusting the request headers. But I don't seem to get it to work.

[image]

In the image, you can see I have the extension set to "On", but the request still fails on the preflight OPTIONS request.
The thing about this request is also that I have set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to `true` in my headers, but this preflight request says it's set to `false`. That is making me think that there is something wrong with my code because I'm also mighty inexperienced with making API requests and setting headers and all.

```
logIn( email: string, password: string ): Observable<any> {
  const authKey = btoa( `${email}:${password}` );
  const headers = new HttpHeaders( {
    Authorization: `basic ${authKey}`,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
  } );
  const params  = new HttpParams().set( 'username', email );
  return this.http.get( 'https://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/user', { headers, params } ).pipe( map( ( user: any ) => {
    if ( user ) {
      localStorage.setItem( 'currentUser', JSON.stringify( { user: { authKey } } ) );
    }
  } ) );
}
```

*Note: I'm building an Angular app*

Who can tell me what is preventing me from making my requests?

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to set CORS headers by javascript. Also cors headers must be response not request headers. Consider using an api proxy. [Here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md) is an example for local development.